# Issue changing value into dynamic parent and child checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [live demo updated](https://jsfiddle.net/n0mfs317/15/)

Problem: Trying to change value according dynamic checkboxes:

When I do click on the parent checkbox should change value="1" on childs

```
<input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" value="1">     
<input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" value="1">
```

When I uncheck the parent should be value="0" on childs

```
<input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" value="0">     
<input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" value="0">
```

**Code**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 1  <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_1').style.display='';return false;"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/512/plus_add_green.png" height="20" width="20"></a>  <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_1').style.display='none';return false;"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/512/minus_remove_green.png" height="20" width="20"></a><br />
  <div id="div_1" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" />Child 1-1 </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" />Child 1-2 </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" />Child 1-3 </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 2  <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_2').style.display='';return false;"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/512/plus_add_green.png" height="20" width="20"></a>  <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_2').style.display='none';return false;"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ie_Bright/512/minus_remove_green.png" height="20" width="20"></a><br />
  <div id="div_2" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" />Child 2-1 </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" />Child 2-2 </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox" />Child 2-3 </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>    
</div>
```

**Script**:

```
$(document).on('change', '.parentCheckBox', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   that.closest('div').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', that.is(':checked'));
   $(this).val($(this).prop('checked')?1:0);
});

$(document).on('change', '.childCheckBox', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var par = that.closest('ul');
    var c = par.find('.childCheckBox').filter(':checked').length;
    var parChk = par.closest('div').parent().find('.parentCheckBox');
    var checked = c > 0;

    $(this).val($(this).prop('checked')?1:0);
    parChk.prop('checked', checked);
    console.log(checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the logic to update children value.

```
$(document).on('change', '.parentCheckBox', function() {
    var that = $(this);
  that.closest('div').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', that.is(':checked')).val(that.is(':checked')?1:0);
});

$(document).on('change', '.childCheckBox', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).val($(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0);
    var par = that.closest('ul');
    var c = par.find('.childCheckBox').filter(':checked').length;
    var parChk = par.closest('div').parent().find('.parentCheckBox');
    var checked = c > 0;

    parChk.prop('checked', checked);
    console.log(checked);
});
```

Comment: Is working https://jsfiddle.net/n0mfs317/11/ but is having a big problem, when the parent is unchecked should change to his childs.

Comment: @JacobFrye I added the logic to parent click

Comment: Is not working at all, please check my new updated post https://jsfiddle.net/n0mfs317/15/ when I check  the parent all his childs should change to value 1 and when the parent is unchecked all chils should have value 0

Comment: @JacobFrye it shouldn't be ``$(this).val($(this).prop('checked')?1:0); ``. it should be ``that.closest('div').find('.childCheckBox').val(that.is(':checked')?1:0);  `` actually just copy my entire code.

Comment: I did your code jsfiddle.net/n0mfs317/17 but when I uncheck the parent doesn't change to  0 and when i check the parent should change to 1.

Comment: @JacobFrye do you mean you want to have parent checkbox value also changed? Then Just add ``$(this).val($(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0);`` to parent event handler too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.childCheckBox', function(e) {

  var childCheckBoxInput = $(e.target);

  if (childCheckBoxInput.is(':checked')) {
    chilCheckBoxInput.val(1);
  } else {
    childCheckBoxInput.val(0);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish, but here are two pretty straight forward examples of what I think you are trying to do.

This is usually not how you use checkboxes. They have one value set, by default all checkboxes has the value 'on'. But you can use 1 or any other value as well. There is no need to change their value. If the checkbox is checked decides if it will post that value or not, if this was a form.

But, just to demonstrate how you can change the values based on change, I have two examples.

**Simplified example:**

*HTML:*

```
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 1-1 </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 1-2 </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 1-3 </li>
  </ul>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
// When checkbox is changed
$('.childCheckBox').on('change', function(e){

  // Check if its checked
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // If checked, set value to 1
    $(this).val(1);
  } else {
    // If not checked, set value to 0
    $(this).val(0);
  }
  // Log value of changed checkbox
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

https://jsbin.com/mewefegopi/edit?html,js,output

**Longer example with parents:**

*HTML:*

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 1
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 1-1 </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 1-2 </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 1-3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 2
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 2-1 </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 2-2 </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" class="childCheckBox">Child 2-3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
// When parent checkbox is changed
$('.parentCheckBox').on('change', function(e){

  var self = this;
  // Get all child checkboxes
  var childs = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.childCheckBox');

  // Go though all childs
 $(childs).each(function(i, e){

   // If parent is checked set child value to 1
   if($(self).prop('checked')) {
     $(this).val(1);
   } else { // ...else set child value to 0
     $(this).val(0);
   }

  });

});
```

https://jsbin.com/qisizudupa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I updated my code and what I want about parent and child

Comment: your second example is almost near.

Comment: Second example does what you ask for. All the child checkboxes change value, 1 if parent is checked and 0 if not checked.
So if you check parent 1, then Child 1-1, Child 1-2 and Child 1-3 will have value 1. This dosen't mean the childs will be checked, just that their value will be 1.
This is also where I do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You usually do not change the value of a checkbox, its value is just 1 or 0, actually if you do not set a value at all it's value will be 'on' by default. If a checkbox is checked it will post it's value, if not checked that value won't be posted.

Comment: Here in this demo https://jsfiddle.net/n0mfs317/17/ the only problem that is missing is that when I uncheck the parent is still on 1 and should change to 0.

Comment: ok I understood but exist the probability to make that? http://jsfiddle.net/n0mfs317/17/